Existence of maximal tree in a graph
Let $X$ be a connected graph, $Y$ be a subgraph which is disjoint union of trees in $X$. Show that there exists a maximal tree containing $Y$ in $X$.
If $Y=\cup_{i\in I} T_i$, where $T_i$'s are tree, then for each $T_i$ there exists a maximal tree in $X$ containing $T_i$.
I found this question in  a book, "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups," by Rotman (page 347, 11.35). A hint given in this book:
Take a partition $P$ of vertices of $X$ such that $f:X \to X/P$ the natural quotient map is a simplicial map. That means it sends a vertex of $X$ to $\operatorname{vert}(X/P)$ and if simplexes in $X$ to simplexes in $X/P$.
How to use this hint?

What is the definition of maximal here?

If it means a tree with no proper super set that is a tree, you can use induction. Just keep adding edges, if there is any edge you can add without creating a cycle.  If there is no such edge, it is maximal.

@JairTaylor It is possible that adding edges you extend  $T_{2j},$ while $T_{2j+1}$ remain unchanged.

@RyszardSzwarc Sorry I don't follow what you mean.

@JairTaylor Let $X=\mathbb{Z}^2$ and the edges connect vertices whose distance is equal $1.$ Let $Y$ consist of all paralel lines $T_i$ for $i\in \mathbb{Z}.$ We start adding edges $[(0,0),(0,1)],$ then $[(0,1),(0,2)]$ and so on, i.e. $[(0,n-1),(0,n)]$ at the $n$ step. So we keep adding edges according to your recipe. As a result we get a tree containing $T_i$ for all $i\ge 0,$ But this tree does not contains any $T_i$ for $i<0.$

Oh, I was assuming this was a finite graph.  That's usually the case in graph theory so it would be helpful if OP had clarified that $X$ here is not necessarily finite.

Squeeze every tree $T_j$ to a vertex
(formally it can be done by introducing an appropriate recurrence relation and its equivalence classes). In this way we obtain a new connected graph. By a known theorem every connected  graph admits a spanning tree. This spanning tree and the collection of $T_j$ form a tree in the original graph.

What is the known theorem??

Re-edited. The proof of the theorem becomes easy when the graph is finite.
